# to comment rows that contain my_string in crontab

Tags: cron

In order to manager blackouts, in my crontab, I would like to automate the following task: "to comment rows that contain my_string".
And after that, another command (or script) to remove these comments.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want to write a script that comment out some lines of the file /etc/crontab, I suppose, and you are inside of a Linux-alike environment: right?

Issue next command:

```
sudo sed -i /etc/crontab -e '/my_string/s/^/#/'
```

To remove the comment, issue:

```
sudo sed -i /etc/crontab -e '/my_string/s/^#//'
```

You don't need to restart the cron service after that.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'm working on Solaris and my sed just have -e -f and -n options. Perhaps I will need to use a temporary file

Comment: Indeed, you will need a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Pierre et my friend Wildemar, here is a method:

## To put the comments

crontab -l  | sed '/my_string/s/^/#/' > cron_temp
crontab cron_temp
rm cron_temp

## To remove the comments

crontab -l  | sed '/my_string/s/#//' > cron_temp
crontab cron_temp
rm cron_temp